# Pass Javascript Array to Polymer 'post-service' html

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

I'm still new at Polymer and I'm slowly learning how to use Polymer by modifiying the examples that Google provided.

But I'm encountering a bit of an issue.

I have a Array in Javascript:

```
var dash = [{"uid": 1,
"text" : "It's a TOWN!",
"username" : "Sam112",
"avatar" : "../ToolKit/images/avatar-01.svg",
"favorite": false,
"num" : "Standard"}];

function addto ()
{
    dash.push({"uid": 2,
        "text" : "It's a BABY!",
        "username" : "Pete223",
        "avatar" : "../ToolKit/images/avatar-01.svg",
        "favorite": false,
        "num" : "Standard"});
}
```

And I want to put this data in the 'post-service' template file:

```
    <script>

    Polymer('post-service',
    {
        created: function()
        {
            this.posts = dash;
        },

        postsLoaded: function()
        {
            this.posts = this.$.ajax.response.slice(0);
        },

        setFavorite: function(uid, isFavorite)
        {
            console.log('Favorite changed: ' + uid + ", now: " + isFavorite);
        }
    });

</script>
```

So i called the addto() function and then I loaded the index.html Polymer file and i expected to load data from the Array...

But It loads the Array, but the added object ( from addto() ), doesn't load.

It apparently loads from the original array but not the new entry from the addto() function.

Is there a way to make 'post-service' load an array when it changes? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not working because `dash` is only assigned to `this.posts` in the `created` handler, so typically on construction of the polymer element. If you call `addTo` afterwards, it will change `dash`, but `dash` will never be assigned to `this.posts` again.

Maybe add the `addTo` function to the element itself? Like:

```
    Polymer('post-service',
    {
        created: function()
        {
            this.posts = dash;
        },

        addTo: function(arr)
        {
            this.posts.push (arr)
        },

        postsLoaded: function()
        {
            this.posts = this.$.ajax.response.slice(0);
        },

        setFavorite: function(uid, isFavorite)
        {
            console.log('Favorite changed: ' + uid + ", now: " + isFavorite);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kroonwijk!

I eventually gave up and I just used local-storage and JSON's stringify and parse to transfer between the Polymer element and my Javascript Data.

```
    localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(dash);
```

And on the Polymer Side...

```
    Polymer('post-service',
    {
        created: function()
        {
            this.posts = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);
        },

        postsLoaded: function()
        {
            this.posts = this.$.ajax.response.slice(0);
        },

        setFavorite: function(uid, isFavorite)
        {
            console.log('Favorite changed: ' + uid + ", now: " + isFavorite);
        }
    });
```

Much easier, sorry IE 7 and lower...